# Toilet Sounds like it is flushing but it is not

Tags: toilet

2 or 3 times a day, my toilet sounds like it is filling up - you hear what sounds like water running into the bowl and then a shut off noise but it is not flushing. I've taken the lid off and checked. I don't see any change in my water bill so I don't think there is a leak. Sometimes there is a gurgling sound for several minutes but also stops.

I've lived in the house 5 years but it is the original toilet from 9/1999. It looks to me like the insides are not the original.

Any ideas what this might be and how to stop the problem? It's actually woken me up in the middle of the night.

Answer (score 4):

Your flapper is leaking, allowing water to slowly drain. Once the water level drops enough, the float valve opens to refill the tank to the correct level.

Remove the tank cover and check the flapper for a sticky hinge or mildew accumulation. Often, just a cleaning will fix the problem. Otherwise, the flapper can usually be replaced separately for a small cost.